# summation of Newton symbol product

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Anyone has idea how to simplify this summation:
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}\binom{M-1+k}{k}\binom{M-1+N-k}{N-k}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $|x|<1$, and for any positive integer $m$,
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{m}}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{-m}{i}(-x)^i
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{m-1+k}{k}x^k.$$
Hence, by the [Cauchy product of series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_infinite_series),
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}\binom{M-1+k}{k}\binom{M-1+N-k}{N-k}$$
is the coefficient of $x^N$ of the product
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{M}}\cdot \frac{1}{(1-x)^{M}}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2M}}.$$
By the above formula, such coefficient is equal to
$$\binom{2M-1+N}{N}.$$